# Error: Parameters cannot be modified at the same time in AWS Document DB Elastic Cluster (CDK/ Cloudformation)

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-documentdb

I created an AWS Elastic DocDbCluster using CDK and provided an already-present Security group. Later on, I changed my Stack to create a security group from CDK and provide this ID to the docDbCluster and redeployed the stack.

Cloudformation is throwing an error:

```
DocumentDBStack failed: Error: The stack named DocumentDBStack failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource handler returned message: "Shard configuration, network parameters (security groups and subnets) and Authentication parameters (secret ARN and password) cannot be modified at the same time. (Service: DocDbElastic, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 53edd146-bc75-40b6-a756-af6df4d019c2)" (RequestToken: c4d30044-c9c1-2ec2-24d2-ed5bde5784e9, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

CDK Code:

```
/**
 * Create a new Security Group
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.html
 */
const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'docDbSG', {
  vpc: vpc,
});

// Add ingress rules
securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.ipv4("10.0.0.0/8"), ec2.Port.allTraffic(), "allow from internal network");

/**
 * Create a new Document DB Elastic Cluster
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_docdbelastic.CfnCluster.html
 */
new docdbelastic.CfnCluster(this, 'elasticDocDbCluster', {
  adminUserName: props!.docDbAdminUserName,
  adminUserPassword: "password",
  authType: props!.docDbAuthType,
  clusterName: props!.docDbClusterName,
  shardCapacity: props!.docDbShardCapacity,
  shardCount: props!.docDbShardCount,
  subnetIds: props!.dataSubnets,
  vpcSecurityGroupIds: [securityGroup.securityGroupId],
});
```

I even ran a CDK Diff and it shows a single change:

```
Resources
[+] AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup docDbSG docDbSGDD5902
[~] AWS::DocDBElastic::Cluster elasticDocDbCluster elasticDocDbCluster
 └─ [~] VpcSecurityGroupIds
     └─ @@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
        [ ] [
        [-]   "sg-1234"
        [+]   {
        [+]     "Fn::GetAtt": [
        [+]       "docDbSGDD5902",
        [+]       "GroupId"
        [+]     ]
        [+]   }
        [ ] ]
```